# How to get the patch update for vulnerabilities in MSXML6.0?

Tags: msxml, msxml6

I am using MSXML version 6.0 in my Visual studio application.Recently I found some risks of using MSXML6 due to the below vulnerabilities reported in **National Vulnerability Database**(NVD - [nvd@nist.gov](https://stackoverflow.com)).

Please refer the below table

| Vulnerabilities | Windows version | Windows OS Update | Download link mentioned in Database |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CVE-2019-1060 (MS XML Remote Code Execution Vulnerability) | Windows 10 for x64-based Systems | KB4520011 | https://catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB4520011 |
| CVE-2019-1057 | Windows 10 for x64-based Systems | KB4512497 | https://catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB4512497 |
| CVE-2019-0795 | Windows 10 for x64-based Systems | KB4493470 | https://catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB4493470 |
| CVE-2013-0006 | Windows 10 for x64-based Systems | KB4493475 | https://catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB4493475 |

It is mentioned in the NVD, the vulnerabilities are solved by Microsoft in Security patch updates.

But when I checked the mentioned links, it was not working (say [https://catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB4520011 for](https://catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB4520011%C2%A0for) CVE-2019-1060)

So I couldn't figure out the exact MSXML6 patch version in which all the above vulnerabilities are solved.

So it would be really appreciable, if anyone share the working **valid link of the update or patch version information.**

Below is my development environment setup:-

1. OS name                  :Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise LTSC
2. OS version               :10.0.17763 Build 17763
3. Compiler                 : 64-bit
4. Visual studio version    : VS 2017 (18.9.28307.222 Release)

Thanks in advance.